# How to access http://localhost/~username/Sites folder from iPhone which is connected to the same network

Tags: macos, apache, localhost, webserver

**I'm not using WAMP or MAMP**, I'm just using the inbuilt web server on mac. I have all my websites developed on `http://192.xxx.x.x/~username/Sites` folder and need to access some of them in my iPhone.

I found my mac's ip address (`192.xxx.x.x`) and entered it on my iPhone and it's working fine. But when I enter `http://192.xxx.x.x/~username/Sites` it says,

`Forbidden, you don't have permission to access this resource.`

Is this something to do with Firewall ?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of permision issues, 
You should check your `etc/apache2/users` there check `username.conf`.

> If there is no username.conf , get your short username and create a file shortusername.conf.
>   Use whoami to get short username, e.g my username is San create San.conf at that location..
>   Use sudo nano shortusername.conf to edit file and add this bit

```
<Directory "/Users/username/Sites/">
AllowOverride All
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Now restart your server by :
`sudo apachectl restart`
This worked for me...